# Search the source code to check from the txt file which functions are used, but skip the commented functions

Tags: linux, shell, grep

I have txt file with listed functions and I need to search my source code to check which of this functions are actually called. But there is problem because some of those functions are commented in source code and I got wrong result. And I need to print those results in 2 txt files, used and not used functions.

I tried this but it only does the search and doesn't leave out the commented functions. I also tried to print the entire line where the function is mentioned, but I had no luck, obviously I didn't use grep well.

```
filename='functions.txt'
while read -r line; do
find -name "*.c" | xargs grep $line  && echo $line >> used.txt || echo $line >> not_used.txt
done < $filename
```

For example in my txt file I have list:
Config
Boot
Startup
And in my source code it should search for it. It doesn't matter who uses it, as long as it is used in the source code. But there are some places where i have those functions commented like
/* Boot...../* or

//Boot //
and I would like to skip those one. Everything else is fine. Or just to print whole line where I found I match and I will search manually for comments

Comment: Can you give an example of a function you want and one that is commented out?  /* or //.  I would probably look for a tool that understands c rather than try to parse it badly.  What if a macro calls a function, say, but concatenating two arguments?

Comment: For example in my txt file I have list:
Config
Boot
Startup.
And in my source code it should search for it. It doesn't matter who uses it, as long as it is used in the source code. But there are some places where i have those functions commented like /* Boot...../* or //Boot // and I would like to skip those one. Everything else is fine. Or just to print whole line where I found I match and I will search manually for comments

Comment: Update your question instead responding with a comment.  This makes it easier for people to see.  What about code commented out with a #if block?  Check you cscope, btw.

Comment: Ok. Probably then it will be easier just to print whole line when it finds a match

Comment: What programming language is the source file written in? Can `/* .... */` be nested? How does a function definition look like? If you could restrict the problem to, say, C or C++, I would first run the preprocessor over the source code. AFIK, the preprocessors not only expand macros, but also remove comments, and you have an easier time to parse  the code.

Comment: Here is problem if I will use at some time different config it will remove #ifdef